# Trying to draw a hollow point over the x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using geom_point to draw some points.  I am using scale_shape_manual to set the point shape to the hollow square (shape #22). I then use scale_color_manual to fill the squares with the color white.

The above is working as expected.  However, some of my points lay directly on (or very close to) my x-axis.  In these cases, what I am seeing is the hollow box with the x-axis going through it.  What I really want is for the white-filled box to lay on top of the x-axis, covering it.

[image: A picture of what I do not want:]

Thanks for the suggestions!
Here is a simple code example that demonstrates my issue:

```
library("ggplot2")

theme_set(theme_classic()) 
theme_update(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

x_values <- c(1,2)
y_values <- c(3,4)

plot_data <- data.frame(x_values, y_values)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=x_values, y=y_values)) + 
  geom_point(size=5, shape=22, colour="red", fill="white") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip="off")
```

This is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE4Cx.png)

You can see that the point in the upper right (x=2, y=4) is a hollow box.
The point in the lower left (x=1, y=3) is also a hollow box, but you can see the x-axis inside the box. I want to cover the x-axis there.

I thought the fill would do it, but it seem the x-axis is getting drawn last.

Just to show that fill is working, here is the plot if you set the fill to green:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLlTj.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. A suggestion, take the description of what you did in the first paragraph and include the code you wrote to get your desired results below the description. Next you want a test on all boxes to see if they are are `y +/- 0.5` (or there abouts) and render those solid white, otherwise hollow. Which I don't know how to do at the moment, but I think the words say what you want while the picture shows what you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Shapes 21 through 25 have separate border and fill colors. The border color is set with `color` and the interior fill color is set with `fill`. So, if you want every point marker to have the same shape and color, you can do the following:

```
geom_point(shape=22, colour="red", fill="white")
```

You would use `scale_colour_manual()` and/or `scale_fill_manual()` to set the colour/fill mappings manually in cases where you're mapping a data column to the `colour` or `fill` aesthetics, but the idea is the same. Use `colour` for the border of the point marker and `fill` for the interior. Likewise, you would use `scale_shape_manual()` to choose the specific shape mappings when you map a data column to the `shape` aesthetic.

**UPDATE:** I'd forgotten that the axis is drawn "on top" of the points, which becomes apparent when you turn off clipping. You might need to turn off the standard x-axis and draw your own. There might be a better way, but nothing's coming to mind at the moment. Here's an example:

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=x_values, y=y_values)) + 
  annotate(x=0.95, xend=2.05, y=3, yend=3, geom='segment') +
  annotate(x=seq(1,2,0.25), xend=seq(1,2,0.25), y=3, yend=2.99, geom="segment") +
  geom_point(size=5, shape=22, colour="red", fill="white") +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") +
  theme(axis.line.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.95,2.05), expand=c(0,0), breaks=seq(1,2,0.25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the problem of getting the filled point to be on top of the x-axis.